# cakephp multiple forms

Tags: php, cakephp

I wish to have have multiple forms under each table row on a page with cakephp. I am not sure how to change the input names to allow this.

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('member_no'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('first_name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('last_name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('total_points'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('date_joined'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($members as $member): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['member_no']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['first_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['last_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['total_points']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($member['Member']['date_joined']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $member['Member']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $member['Member']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $member['Member']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $member['Member']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        /// This is the form for each record
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Point', array('action' => 'add')); ?>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><?php echo __('Add Point'); ?></legend>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('member_id',array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$member['Member']['id']));
                    echo $this->Form->input('points');
                ?>
                </fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP will produce the forms as normal, as long as they are uniquely named. You might consider appending the member id onto the name of the form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Point'.$member['Member']['id'], array('action' => 'add')); ?>
```

You can use this (or any other method you'd like) to make the forms unique. You may also have a problem with non-unique field names. In that case, use a similar trick to have all unique field names in both forms and fields if they are from the same controller.

Comment: I thought of this but I get missing Point1s controller

Comment: You will have to manually specify the controller if naming the form different things. `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Point'.$member['Member']['id'], array('controller' => 'myController','action' => 'add')); ?>`